# Converting an array into Array List

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

Hi I have two Java Files as below:

```
            case 6:  
                System.out.println("List All Property Details For Rent >>>");
//              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Property_list));
                int i=0;
                while(i<count){
                    ppty.property_list[i].viewPropertyDetails("RENT");
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                break; 

        }

    }




    }

}
```

Guys, This is basically an array of properties, and a Menu to do some operation with the list. I was planning to improve my code with a java ArrayList, because its more dynamic in nature. Could anyone tell me how I can convert this array (property_list) into an ArrayList? What are the changes do I need to make? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also is there anyway I can improve my Menu5(To remove a property), currently am using kind of  "cheating method" by changing the status.. Much appreciate ur kind advices

Comment: You can use `Arrays.asList()`

Comment: @Sanjeev: You mean for the remove?

Comment: Am  very new to java.. Sorry

Comment: Because I can use `ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strings));
a.remove(i);` to remove an object from array also..

Comment: Not really Sanjeev. I don't want to use any extra code to change my array into an ArrayList. I want to replace my codes with the arraylist methods..

Answer (score 1):

Your commented code is perfectly valid for initiliazing the arrayList.

```
ArrayList<Property> property_list = new ArrayList<Property>();
```

In java 7 or later you don't need to specify the second Property:

```
ArrayList<Property> property_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Unlike the java Array you don't use bracket notation to access your variables you use  .get(int index):

```
ppty.property_list.get(count)
```

To add a value you use .add(Object item);

```
ppty.property_list.add(new Property());
```

And you don't need to remember the size of ArrayList by storing it in a variable. The ArrayList has the .size() method which returns the number of elements in it.

---

Extra tips:

- Here you can find extra methods the ArrayList has https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
- You have setters and getters in your Property object. You could set the member variables to private and use them.
- You should replace that ppty method with the constructor method like so:

  ```
  public Property(int streetno,String streetname,
              String suburb,
              int postalcode,String contactperson,
              String office,int phonenumber,
              String openTime,String propertytype,
              double price, String date){
                  this.StreetNumber = streetno;
          this.StreetName=streetname;
          this.Suburb=suburb;
          this.PostalCode=postalcode;
          this.ContactPerson=contactperson;
          this.PhoneNumber=phonenumber;
          this.Office=office;
          this.OpenTime=openTime;
          this.PropertyType=propertytype;
          this.PropertyPrice=price;
          this.Date = date;
  ```

  ```
  }
  ```
- This property_list should not be inside your Property object. This is something you should handle outside the object. For example in your `public void displayMenuPanel()` you could say `ArrayList<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>()`. If you put the list inside the object then it is tied with that object. If the object goes, the list goes.